# SMTP dot-stuffing within MIME boundaries

Tags: smtp, libcurl, mime

I guess I ran into a dot-stuffing problem sending SMTP messages. What i basically want to do is to send a message with a text and a attachment part. 
In my example I defined a multipart/mixed message like following:

```
    Mime-version: 1.0
    Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="YJiPVI9C2M93dRDm"

    --YJiPVI9C2M93dRDm
    Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
    Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
    Content-Disposition: inline

    Message
    .

   --YJiPVI9C2M93dRDm
   Content-Type: application/gzip
   Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
   Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=2015-06-22-114558.tar.gz

   H4sIAFbZh1UCA+2dXW/dNhKGc72/QujVLtAmIocjSqdXbbH9AJJt0G63F0URuPZJYdT2MezjNP33
   FXkcbyQxh6TmnX4AOTdpUs3D0ejlkOKXbGv4o7b7yNqPjHHM/ZNH8F87/jxz/HP8zf+M/20sO+PZ

   --YJiPVI9C2M93dRDm--
```

If I send the SMTP massage with libcurl like described above i will get connection timeouts. The problem is the single point (after "Message"). I know that this is a escape sign in SMTP, but it should be interpreted as a  "normal" point. So how to do this? Is the mime body correct? Do i need to masquerade the single point?

Comment: You can add a Content-type:text and send the . in that.

Comment: SMTP dot stuffing should be completely transparent.  Because a lone dot signifies the end of the `DATA` transmission, the line will have to be transmitted as dot-stuffed *newline* *dot* *dot* *newline* but immediately reverted back to, and stored as, *newline* *dot* *newline* on the receiving end (where *newline* stands for a CR LF pair, but you might get away with whatever local line ending convention you have).

Comment: Indentation in your example is wacky.  It looks like every MIME part is indented one space more than the next one.

Comment: How are you sending this, and where?  Maybe include a code snippet. If this is repeatable, you have found a bug either in libcurl or in the SMTP server you are talking to.  (I would speculate on the former; I didn't even know you could use libcurl for SMTP?)

Comment: Maybe see also http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1456/

Comment: @tripleee, thanks for the fast reply. Libcurl is providing some basic smtp features, but you still have to define your message body by yourself. I tried serveral mail accounts (e.g gmail).  So i guess i have to dig deeper.